# How to pass properties to a higher order component, when the wrapped component is a generic type?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I need to use `Component extends FunctionComponent<Properties>` instead of `ComponentType`, because this was originally a method of a parameterized class. The component should get properties from `useParams()`.

```
import {useParams} from "react-router-dom";
import {FunctionComponent} from "react";
    
function wrap<Properties extends Record<string, string>, Component extends FunctionComponent<Properties>>(WrappedComponent: Component) {
        function InnerComponent() {
            const parameters = useParams<Properties>();
            return <WrappedComponent {...parameters}/>;
        }
    
        return InnerComponent;
    }
```

I get:

> TS2322: Type 'Readonly<[Properties] extends [string] ? Params<Properties> : Partial<Properties>>' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & LibraryManagedAttributes<Component, PropsWithChildren<Properties>>'.
> Type 'Readonly<[Properties] extends [string] ? Params<Properties> : Partial<Properties>>' is not assignable to type 'LibraryManagedAttributes<Component, PropsWithChildren<Properties>>'.

It seems to me like I have to define `Properties` in a way, that would be compatible with `Component`.

Comment: Please provide reproducible example with all imports. Where did you get `useParams` ?

Comment: You can use [this](https://tsplay.dev/WG56oN) solution. However not all type will be infered. Could you pelase provide an example of how you want to call `wrap` hoc ?

Comment: @captain-yossarian Your solution drops all the generic parameters and I need to keep them. The idea is to simply pass the URL parameters to the component as properties.

Comment: Sure, my solution is not even solution I know, this is why I'm asking you to share an example of how you call this function to be able to test it. I'm not familiar with reat router